# Which statistical method to use for data with factor-based dependent variable

Tags: logit, statistical-learning, inference

I have a data set with many variables which are factors or discrete string values. For example students are allowed to choose any one of three courses offered. The choice of student may depend upon the price, timing, location, teacher etc.

Now linear regression as I understand is out of question here because it doesn't work with dependent variables having discrete string values.

Another choice available in statistics is logistics regression but as I understand it, its outcome is dichotomous(e.g., success/failure, yes/no, chosen/not chosen  or died/lived.) 
If I apply logistic regression on my data will it help me find the answer that which factors effect the choice of students in choosing a course?  Or in another example what factors were effecting the choice of a person decided to sell a product by joint venture mechanism instead of distribution and by how much?

If there are any other statistical methods available for handling these types of questions, please let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, the method you are looking for is multinomial (polytomous) logistic regression (mlogit in Stata, for R see http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm). In most packages the outcome category that is most frequent becomes the reference category and you get two sets of regression results for the other two categories as compared to the reference category outcome. You can always change the reference outcome if preferred. The interpretation of the coefficients is the same as logistic regression - log odds, and again in comparison to the reference outcome. Another possibility is to use conditional logistic regression.